# Using layoutparams in relativeLayout with dp

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout, margin, layoutparams

I m making an app and i want to be able to move a view using its margins dynamically.
I tried using this :

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)cover.getLayoutParams();
params.leftMargin= 470;
params.topMargin= 20;
cover.setLayoutParams(params); (cover is an ImageView)
```

The problem with this code its that it uses px instead of dp. I also tried using DisplayMetrics to convert my px values to dp but failed . Can you help me ?

Comment: What is cover  button?

Comment: cover is an imageview (it is written is the code)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/TypedValue.html#applyDimension(int, float, android.util.DisplayMetrics)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to set margin according to dpi -

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) MyActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
```

Now you can set margin as -

```
params.leftMargin = Math.round(470 * displayMetrics.density);
```