# In Android, FIT_XY crops my image slightly

Tags: android

I have a (evoluted version of a) circle in a png, with a big border, and when displayed in an `ImageView` with `FIT_XY` it it cropped and appears a little squared, any idea ?

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(80, 80));
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.myimg);
img.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(80, 80));
img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);  // tried FIT_XY too
img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
layout.addView(img);
```

Comment: Is there anything else in "layout"? If not, you shouldn't need to add it, the single ImageView should be sufficient.

Comment: yes there are other things

Answer (score 0):

Try to use fixed size (specify directly height and width) and fit_center scale type or try  to use adjustviewbounds attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

1. Try to use fixed size (specify directly height and width) and fit_center scale type or try  to use adjustviewbounds attribute. (OP indicated this did not work in their case)
2. Try adding a layout_margin to the image. If the image content fits tight to the image bounds, borders and such on the parent could get in the way.
3. Make sure that the LayoutParams match the parent Layout (in this case RelativeLayout.LayoutParams). Not sure if this is an issue, but I have been bitten by this in the past.

   ```
   RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.test); // <-- Parent
   ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
   img.setImageResource(R.drawable.cow);
   img.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(400, 400)); // <-- Use Parent layout type
   img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER); 
   layout.addView(img);
   ```
4. new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(400, 400) uses pixels and not dip. If you are actually wanting your layout sizing to be in dip see this post: [Using layoutparams in relativeLayout with dp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799968/using-layoutparams-in-relativelayout-with-dp)

Comment: After the edit, that's exactly what I have, (`LayoutParams = RelativeLayout.*`) and I wanted pixels, yes, I still don't understand the problem, I will try the margins